# Using MySQL REGEXP to filter string with Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm, mysql-regexp

I have a model which have `FileField` field and in this model we have millions of records.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    media = models.FileField(upload_to=my_function, db_index=True)
    ...
```

These media records are stored in database like;

- media/some/folder/filename.jpg
- media/filename.jpg
- media/2021091240-10328.JPG
- media/aXay-123.jpeg
- media/some/another/folder/202110-12-12.jpeg

etc. and I need to find records which are not have nested path like `/some/folder/` or `/some/another/folder/` with django orm `__iregex` lookup.

So, I tried something like;

```
MyModel.objects.filter(media__iregex=r"^media/[0-9a-zA-Z\-][.][a-zA-Z]")
```

but it does not match and I do not understand to write proper regex [[mysql regexp]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

How can I do filter with mysql regexp with using Django orm to get records with only have pattern like; `media/filename.extension`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has no quantifier, and thus will pick *exactly one* character for the `[0-Aa-zA-Z\-]` character group.

You can simply filter out elements that contain at least two slashes with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(media__iregex=r'^media/[^/]+$')
```

Comment: two slashes sure! simple is better than complex. thank you! `[^/]` is for not containing `/` and `+` is for match one or more instance and `$` is for specifying end of the string right?

Comment: @uedemir: yes, exactly!